# CovarianceSampling always return the first n point

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have an organized point cloud grabbed from an RGB-D sensor. I am trying to apply `CovarianceSampling` on it. However, I am getting very strange result which is the first N point of the cloud.

The code I am using:

```
//Grab the point cloud(point_cloud) and compute the normals(point_cloud_normal)
pcl::CovarianceSampling<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> covariance_sampling;
covariance_sampling.setInputCloud(point_cloud);
covariance_sampling.setNormals(point_cloud_normal);
covariance_sampling.setNumberOfSamples(4800);
covariance_sampling.setKeepOrganized(true);
covariance_sampling.filter(filtered_indices->indices);
```

This does not happen if I use another sampler such as `NormalSpaceSampling`.

What did I miss?